# Magento product csv import, only import last image

Tags: magento, csv, import, product

I am trying to import products using a csv file in Magento 1.5.0.1. I uploaded all the images to the folder /media/import but only the last image is imported. For example, if I upload 4 products with the corresponding images, all of them are imported but only the last one has its image.

Does anybody know what is happening? or how to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Magento is deleting the image files as it imports them, and so the images are not there for the following products. You can use the patch I uploaded in http://www.lexitconsulting.com/2012/06/fixing-the-magento-product-import-script/ to fix the problem in the importer, so you can add all the images at once.